# Switch windows of an application behavior change in 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Before I upgraded to 19.04 "Switch windows of an application" used to switch windows of the current application. For example, if I was using a web browser(focused) and had multiple windows open, I would use the "Switch windows of an application" function to immediately cycle through the windows. Since upgrading to 19.04, this same function starts by cycling through the windows of an application which is not focused. I haven't figured out the logic of which application is chooses. Interestingly, this doesn't happen with every application. Terminator, for example, seems to be cycling through its own windows when in focus and using the window switch function. Anybody else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

Wayland was the problem. When I switched the login setting from "Gnome" to "Gnome on Xorg" the probem was fixed.