# Has there been a change in 19.04 with switching applications using (Super + tab)?

Tags: 19.04, task-management

I've noticed that using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in 19.04 starts on the focused application which is not very efficient for quickly switching back and forth between applications.

The old functionality was that when you typed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it would start on the last application you had focused, not the current. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I believe you may have accidentally asked this question twice. The possible duplicate is [Switch windows of an application behavior change in 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139218/switch-windows-of-an-application-behavior-change-in-19-04). This is the better worded question so I recommend you delete the other.

Comment: @RaidPinata No, not exactly. But whatever fixes this problem will most likely fix that problem. This question focuses on the application switcher. The other question is about the window switcher (mutliple windows per application). I use both functions constantly.

Comment: @RaidPinata I updated the description of [Switch windows of an application behavior change in 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139218/switch-windows-of-an-application-behavior-change-in-19-04)

Answer (score 2):

Wayland was the problem. When I switched the login setting from "Gnome" to "Gnome on Xorg" the probem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No, I am not seeing that behavior. When I super+tab the list starts with the current application but the most recent previous application is highlighted immediately. I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 without Wayland support. If you can give me some more info maybe we can troubleshoot why yours is different.

Comment: ok, good, I was hoping this wasn't the new norm. Thanks for answering. I wish I could tell you more. Evidently there are more players influencing the key mappings and behavior. I think I started with Ubuntu 16.04 on this system. Over the year/s I have used different desktop environments, used the tweak tool, and made various customizations. Do you know of a way to reset things? Ideally short of wiping everything clean.